# How to Trigger this Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var IE = document.all?true:false
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove = getMousePos;
// Temporary variables to hold mouse x-y pos.s
var tempX = 30;
var tempY = 30;

function getMousePos(e) {
  if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
  } else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
    tempX = e.pageX
    tempY = e.pageY
  }  
  // catch/correct negative values 
  if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
  if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

  // show the position values in the form
  document.MouseDisplay.MouseX.value = tempX;
  document.MouseDisplay.MouseY.value = tempY;
  return true;
}

// execute function
if (tempY < 30) {
 alert('tempY is found to be less than 30');
}

</script>
```

I found this code at hotscript and codelifter http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html, it was from an old thread but I believe it's got what I need to achieve. I want to execute a function whenever the mouse Y position is less than 30.

I'm a beginner at programming, hope that I can slowly learn from samples here.

My question is, why is the alert command not triggered? What am I missing here. I did a simple button to call the function it works tho.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
alert('tempY is found to be less than 30');
}
</script>
```

Comment: A better solution would be to have a fixed element, 30px high docked to the top of the screen, and have a `onmouseover` handler set on it.

Comment: Your alert will never trigger in that sample, you check once on load if tempY is less than 30, it isn't since you set it to 30 at the top.

Comment: When you display `alert` in mousemove, be careful it's extremely annoying and you keep getting these alerts one after the other while debugging, although in your case it's slightly different, but still.

Comment: Since you stated that you're a beginner, I'd suggest that you try some easier code. One the other hand, the code you have there is plain awful. I'd advise taking it easy and start with some well-proven concepts, not a script you found on some random website.

Comment: @dombenoit I think we misunderstood a bit. I wanted the alert to trigger only when the tempY is less than 30 according to the mouse position on the page, not on page load. If I set it temporary value to less than 30, the alert is triggered just find on every page load.

Comment: @Christian This thing is working, I was trying to work this out base off a site that I stumble upon. I'm not really a good developer but I work close with it, so I'm hoping I can learn a bit as I try to do my own personal project. On the side note, can you explain why the code is plain awful?

Comment: @Truth That's a brilliant concept man, thanks! I'll give this method a try.

Comment: @Randize The code is using some of the worst parts of javascript, such as accessing elements by name rather than proper DOM traversal (eg, by id). The code in itself is quite unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried your code but assuming it does work when the mouse moves, to see your alert just move that line inside the function :

```
var IE = document.all?true:false
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove = getMousePos;
// Temporary variables to hold mouse x-y pos.s
var tempX = 30;
var tempY = 30;

    function getMousePos(e) {
      if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
        tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
      } else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
        tempX = e.pageX
        tempY = e.pageY
      }  
      // catch/correct negative values 
      if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
      if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

      // show the position values in the form
      document.MouseDisplay.MouseX.value = tempX;
      document.MouseDisplay.MouseY.value = tempY;

      // execute function
      if (tempY < 30) {
       alert('tempY is found to be less than 30');
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hey it worked!! I originally tried this way, BUT below the 'return'. Thanks a lot dombenoit. Didn't know it had a big difference, gotta learn more about 'return'. Still don't get what it's for.

Comment: Glad to help, as far as return goes it's only to make a function return a value, which is optional.